# How do I plot the equation for a line with x and y in log such as log y = 0.84*(log x/10^45) + 46?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I've been struggling with plotting the line:

log y = (0.84 +/- 0.03)*(log x/ 10^45) + (44.06 +/- 0.01)

For context, x is the mid-Infrared luminosity and y is the X-ray luminosity for quasars. The problem is that I've tried plotting it normally as one does with say

```
x = np.linspace(0, 10**50, 100)
y = 0.84*x/10**45 + 44
plt.plot(x, y, linestyle='-')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
```

But this is obviously wrong. I am plotting this line along with points for the data. The data itself is plotted in log space. Right now, I'm going around in circles trying to figure this out. Essentially, I need help in figuring out how to plot log y vs log x for a line.

Thank you!

Comment: you never called a plotting command

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/usage.html

Comment: wait, are you asking about the math? because your math is way off too

Comment: `10**45` and `10**50` are *very* large numbers, and doing floating-point with them could lead to some wonky things.

Comment: The equation has x/10**45 so I need to work with that since the data is of that order

Comment: I assume you're using the equation from the abstract of https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/837/2/145

Comment: I think your equation needs to change to have "log(x/ 10^45)" and subsequently `logy = 0.84 * np.log(x/1e45) + 44`. You should also use `np.logspace` rather than `np.linspace` for setting the values of `x` and `plt.semilogx(x, logy)`

Comment: Yes!! I'm plotting the X-ray vs mid-IR luminosity function for my AGN data but I can't seem to get it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

midir = np.logspace(40, 50, 100)
logxray = 0.84 * np.log10(midir / 1e45) + 44

plt.semilogx(midir, logxray, linestyle="-")
plt.show()
```

Note that this will show the x-axis labels with the notation 10^X and the y-axis just a Y (despite both showing the log-values). If you wanted them to be consistent you could do, e.g.:

```py
logmidir = np.linspace(40, 50, 100)
logxray = 0.84 * (logmidir - 45) + 44
plt.plot(logmidir, logxray)
plt.show()
```